# Jquery script working when inside the html file but fails when imported from an external file

Tags: html, jquery, socket.io

I was following the documentation on socket.io website when I found this problem.

My working code

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(function () {
   var socket = io();
   $('form').submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
     socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
     $('#m').val('');
     return false;
   });
 });
})
</script>
```

When the same jquery script is imported from an external file, it fails.

`client.js` contains the exact same jquery script and in the same directory.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="client.js"></script>
```

Below was the error from console, I'm not able to figure out what it is

```
The resource from “http://localhost:3000/client.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your type to "application/javascript" for that script. Also, if you find that the script isn't loading, add the defer property to the script tag like below.

```
<script type="application/javascript" defer src="./client.js"></script>
```

Lastly, I've seen similar issues where the js isn't located at the source you're referencing. Please make sure your source link is correct.

Comment: It didn't work and also all the files are in the same directory.